# Android Studio, receive notification on date if close to location

Tags: java, android, xml, notifications

Hi Everyone I have to get a `notification` in certain `date` and if the user of the app is near a certain event.

I was thinking about using push `notification` but i have to clue on how to implement in my app.

Do you have some code example to show me? Thanks

I Have read about GCM from google to send notification more easily? how does it work?

Comment: use geofence for near location.. here's the link:  https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html, and about date i m also implementing the same concept, if u succeed on date, then plz tell me..

Comment: What kind of notification you want to show? Do you want to fetch some data from the server to show it as notification or it is only based on date and current location?

Answer (score 0):

here's the little demo about location notification..

```
    public class AreWeThereIntentService extends IntentService {
    private final String TAG = AreWeThereIntentService.class.getName();
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private Gson gson;

    public AreWeThereIntentService() {
        super("AreWeThereIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.SharedPrefs.Geofences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        gson = new Gson();
        // 1. Get the event
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (event != null) {
            if (event.hasError()) {
                onError(event.getErrorCode());
            } else {
                // 2. Get the transition type
                int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
                if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                        transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL ||
                        transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                    List<String> geofenceIds = new ArrayList<>();
                    // 3. Accumulate a list of event geofences
                    for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
                        geofenceIds.add(geofence.getRequestId());
                    }
                    if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                            transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
                        // 4. Pass the geofence list to the notification method
                        onEnteredGeofences(geofenceIds);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void onEnteredGeofences(List<String> geofenceIds) {
        // 1. Outer loop over all geofenceIds
        for (String geofenceId : geofenceIds) {
            String geofenceName = "";
            // 2, Loop over all geofence keys in prefs and retrieve NamedGeofence from SharedPreferences
            Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
                String jsonString = prefs.getString(entry.getKey(), null);
                NamedGeofence namedGeofence = gson.fromJson(jsonString, NamedGeofence.class);
                if (namedGeofence.id.equals(geofenceId)) {
                    geofenceName = namedGeofence.name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // 3. Set the notification text and send the notification
            String contextText =
                    String.format(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Text), geofenceName);
            // 1. Create a NotificationManager
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AppSettings settings = AppSettings.getSettings(getApplication());
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Title))
                    .setContentText(contextText)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contextText))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[0])
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .build();

            try {
                Uri song = Uri.parse(settings.getSdcard());
                if (song == null) {
                    notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                            + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/battlefield");
                } else {
                    notification.sound = Uri.parse(settings.getSdcard());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }

    private void onError(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Geofencing Error: " + i);
    }
}
```

or you can use this sample application code: [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/103540/geofences-googleapiclient)

Comment: no worry..  i will provide you my app link also.. bcz its about to complete. so you can get whole idea about  workflow of this app.